Probles with `rasterize`function
I need to calculate EVI using some modis images, I have already used this code and it worked, but now, when I try to use the rasterize function I am getting this error: Error in (function (cond)  :  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'is.factor': Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].
I separated the EVI layer previously in QGIS, so I am working with a .tif file that  only contains EVI information.
See the code below and the images information. Any help is really welcome.
install.packages("C:/Users/Anto/Downloads/rgdal_1.4-3.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type='source')

library("raster")
library("rgdal")

setwd("C:/Users/Anto/Desktop/Comportamiento_cortisol/GIS_payunia/UTM19S/all_years_spring")

imagen <- raster("20110914_623_UTM19S.tif")   

shape <-readOGR("polig_N_UTM19S.shp")  
zones <- rasterize(shape, imagen, field = "id")  


zones <- rasterize(shape, imagen, field = "id")  

> imagen
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 5120, 4799, 24570880  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 393.1105, 224.7721  (x, y)
extent     : -296537.6, 1590000, 5530378, 6681211  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : 20110914_623_UTM19S.tif 
names      : X20110914_623_UTM19S 
values     : -0.1998, 0.9411  (min, max)

> shape
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 2 
extent      : 469983.2, 539187.8, 5984042, 6016778  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 14
names       : id,        area, count,              sum,              mean,            median,             stdev,               min,               max, count_1,            sum_1,            mean_1,             min_1,             max_1 
min values  :  1, 202291562.4,  2293, 162.667400129139,  0.07094086355392, 0.068999998271465, 0.011263931890283,   0.0168999992311, 0.114500001072884,    2293, 162.667400129139,  0.07094086355392,   0.0168999992311, 0.114500001072884 
max values  :  2, 513447724.7,  5810,  428.03230074048, 0.073671652451029, 0.073600001633167, 0.012532315292168, 0.032499998807907, 0.116499997675419,    5810,  428.03230074048, 0.073671652451029, 0.032499998807907, 0.116499997675419 
> 



I don't see the code for creating the EVI? and the error messages.

2nd comment, you should consider to move on to terra, instead of raster.

3rd comment, you can chose the RSToolbox package that has vegetation indices built in...

I edited the question for clearence

Here is a sample that worked for me, using a Sentinel-2 band, and a polygon shapefile that I digitized. The shapefile has an integer field "id".
library(terra)
# Polygon shapefile
vect_file <- "MyName_shp.shp"
# Sentinel 2 Band
S2_blue  <- "T37NEB_20190416T072621_B02_60m.jp2"
v <- terra::vect(vect_file)
r <- terra::rast(S2_blue)
v
 class       : SpatVector 
 geometry    : polygons 
 dimensions  : 2, 1  (geometries, attributes)
 extent      : 527979.8, 551753.5, 146122.6, 155954.9  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 source      : MyName_shp.shp
 coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 37N (EPSG:32637) 
 names       :    id
 type        : <int>
 values      :     1
                   2
r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1830, 1830, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 60, 60  (x, y)
extent      : 499980, 609780, 90240, 200040  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 37N (EPSG:32637) 
source      : T37NEB_20190416T072621_B02_60m.jp2 
name        : T37NEB_20190416T072621_B02_60m 
v_rasterized <- terra::rasterize(v,r, field = "id")
v_rasterized
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1830, 1830, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 60, 60  (x, y)
extent      : 499980, 609780, 90240, 200040  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 37N (EPSG:32637) 
source(s)   : memory
varname     : T37NEB_20190416T072621_B02_60m 
name        : id 
min value   :  1 
max value   :  2 

I would add that this will not give you the EVI values from the original raster. Rather, the rasterized vector will have the values of the id field for each pixel. If you want to clip the original raster to the extent of the shapefile polygons, what you want is terra::crop() and terra::mask().
HTH

Or perhaps use terra::extract if the goal is to get EVI values for polygons.
